# how to fetch a page's likes from fb by php

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to make a social media audit tool and i want to get likes of a person's Fb page. Basically what i want is i want that person to enter his FB pages URL and then i want to fetch the likes of his page and echo it in my PHP page. Is there any way I can do that without using graph API or any API. I just want a simple piece of code.

I have searched many questions regarding my project on web and on StackOverflow as well but coudn't find what i wanted, at last, I am asking this question. Is there anyone who can help me regarding this?
Thanx in advance.

```
<?php

$file = "https://www.facebook.com/IntellectualIndies/?epa=SEARCH_BOX";
$data = file_get_contents($file);
preg_match_all ('~<div class=\'_4bl9\'>\s*(<div.*?</div>\s*)?(.*?)</div>~is', $data, $matches);
$content = $matches[1];
$total = count($content);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
echo $content[$i]."<br />";
}
?>
```

i tried this code.

Comment: I'm only trying to help by saving you time. You should make an attempt and then you could ask for help on this site. If you can write PHP there is no reason why you can't do this.

Comment: i just updated my question

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API

Comment: The API for Facebook would probably also be 'simple', it just takes some time to learn it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can do that without using graph API or any API

No, scraping is not allowed on Facebook.

There is only one way to do this:

- Apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)
- Use the Graph API with the following endpoint/field: `/page-id?fields=fan_count`

API Reference with example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/